# Slideshow IDE for programmers?

Tags: software-recommendation, slideshow

Is there a slideshow editor similar to Powerpoint, but for Mac, that supports `code` pens and maybe *markdown*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you would call it "similar" to PowerPoint as PowerPoint isn't focused on MarkDown or code, but a nice Mac app is "Deckset" [1](http://www.decksetapp.com).

Another option is to use the browser-based Remark [2](https://remarkjs.com). However it is not a native Mac app as such.